# Solved - Network Connection problem on Ubuntu Server Pro after Installing Kubuntu-Desktop

Tags: server, kubuntu, network-manager, connection

I cannot connect to network after installing Kubuntu Desktop on my Ubuntu Server Pro.

I recently installed Ubuntu Server Pro onto a machine using installer 23.08.01, which I upgraded to version 23.10.1 during the installation. I installed some of the default add-ons, such as NextCloud and the Canonical security updater available to Pro servers. Everything worked as expected. I selected the option to installed 3rd party drivers, like those from Intel.

I then installed Kubuntu Desktop with apt-get. After the installation completed I restarted the server and the GUI came up with the correct server account & login credentials (password).

Since the GUI installation, the network connection no longer works. The desktop icon shows that a connection is detected, but clicking the connection icon reveals a message that says “No available connections.” I cannot download updates.

During both installations I used the motherboard’s ethernet port, using Cat6+ to plug into a switch which then runs to my office’s router. I tried to use a USB-to-Ethernet adapter, but that has not helped, neither has a USB Wi-Fi dongle.

I found a forum answer on how to remove Kubuntu and it’s dependents, while leaving Ubuntu and it’s dependents. (Please correct any improper jargon.) I want to keep Kubuntu because I want to have a GUI to help me conceptualize everything and make windows for managing things if I can. I’m completely new to Linux server’s and have VERY little experience with Windows Server 2012, so I’d rather just fix the network manager (if that is the issue).

Below is the System Info put out by Kubuntu:

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-91-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4600

How would I go about fixing my connection problem?

(I am also having a connection problem on a machine which I just installed Kubuntu OEM Manufacturer version. Maybe Kubuntu network manager is broken??)

Update:
I have determined that the network connection used by the server is working, but that the Kubuntu Desktop's connection is broken. I'm thinking that I need to figure out how to make the network managers run side by side by repairing Kubuntu's network manager, or figure out how to merge them. I am completely new to managing these things, so I am looking through the forum for relevant info.

Comment: Servers use networkd, Desktops use NetworkManager. That the NetworkManager icon does not work on a networkd system seems like expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware that NetworkManager would not work with the server, or the underlying issue - that the two installations don't use the same software. This is why Kubuntu's update manager would not work properly. The real error is that I expected a desktop environment to seamlessly stack on top of a server installation. I will look further into how to "properly" integrate a GUI if possible.

Comment: It's pretty simple: If it's primarily a server with a static address, continue using networkd. If it's moving from network to network, then use NetworkManager. "Proper" integration is mostly handled by the Netplan YAML, which specifies which to use. However, your description that Desktop applications cannot see the network is curious and unusual, and suggests the possibility of another issue.